# How do I install root and su for my LG phone (LM-G820U30b)?

Tags: rooting, lg

How do I root my LG phone?

- Model LM-G820U30b
- Hardware version rev.1.0
- Internal environment SELinux

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Regarding the device model, could you find the brand name? Is it LG G8 ThinQ? Also, is it locked to a specific carrier?

Comment: Possibly related: https://lg-firmwares.com/articles/root-lg-device/

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/lg-g8-g8x-g8s-v50-thinq-unofficial-bootloader-unlock